# Помогите составить запрос с COUNT в mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы: менеджеры и заказы.

Структура таблицы `manager`

```
CREATE TABLE `manager` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `chief_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `chief_id` (`chief_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Структура таблицы `claim`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `claim` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `manager_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `sum` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `manager_id` (`manager_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `claim`

```
ALTER TABLE `claim`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `claim_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`manager_id`) 
  REFERENCES `manager` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `manager`

```
ALTER TABLE `manager`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `manager_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`chief_id`) 
  REFERENCES `manager` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Помогите выбрать менеджеров, у которых количество заказов больше, чем у их руководителя. Не могу никак выбрать. Самый близкий вариант такой

```
SELECT a.first_name, b.first_name, COUNT( a.first_name ) , COUNT( b.first_name ) 
FROM manager a, manager b,  `claim` 
WHERE a.id = b.chief_id AND a.id = claim.manager_id 
GROUP BY a.first_name
```

Но куда впихнуть условие где count одного > count другого, ума не приложу. Если в `where` ставлю `where` `and COUNT( a.first_name ) > COUNT( b.first_name )` получаю ошибку `Invalid use of group function` если ставлю в `having` там тоже ошибка.

Comment: поставьте `having`

Comment: Если ставлю так `SELECT a.first_name, b.first_name, COUNT( a.first_name ), COUNT( b.first_name )
FROM manager a, manager b,  claim 
WHERE a.id = b.chief_id AND a.id = claim.manager_id
GROUP BY a.first_name
HAVING COUNT( a.first_name ) > COUNT( b.first_name )` то в ответе пусто

Comment: `SELECT a.first_name, b.first_name, COUNT( a.first_name ) as count1, COUNT( b.first_name ) as count2
FROM manager a, manager b,  claim 
WHERE (a.id = b.chief_id) AND (a.id = claim.manager_id) and (count1 > count2) 
GROUP BY a.first_name`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я так тоже пробовал, получаю ошибку `Unknown column 'count1' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.first_name, b.first_name, COUNT( a.first_name ) , COUNT( b.first_name ) 
FROM manager a, manager b,  `claim` 
WHERE a.id = b.chief_id AND a.id = claim.manager_id 
GROUP BY a.first_name
having COUNT( a.first_name ) > COUNT( b.first_name )
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я в коменте выше выложил такой же запрос, он возвращает пустой ответ. А должно быть 2 при моей заполненности таблиц

Comment: Можете показать результат который возвращает  запрос без фразы having

Comment: Я сделал запрос. Так получилось `SELECT `m`.`id`, `m`.`first_name`, `m`.`last_name`, `m`.`email` 
    FROM `manager` AS `m`
    JOIN (
        SELECT `manager_id`, COUNT(*) AS `count`
        FROM `claim`
        GROUP BY `manager_id`
    ) AS `mc` ON `mc`.`manager_id` = `m`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT `manager_id`, COUNT(*) AS `count`
        FROM `claim`
        GROUP BY `manager_id`
    ) AS `cc` ON `cc`.`manager_id` = `m`.`chief_id`
    WHERE `chief_id` IS NOT NULL
        AND (`cc`.`count` IS NULL
            OR `mc`.`count` > `cc`.`count`)`